# How to find the max value of an array in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the max value of the first array in the below list, how can I find the min and max also how can I find the index value of the max value of the array?

```
list = [array([ 1.25e-02, -5.79e-03,  7.32e-03, -1.40e-02, 1.73e-02,  3.35e-03,  1.28e-02,  2.59e-02, 4.57e-03,  2.56e-02,  2.44e-03,  1.12e-02]), array([0.00e+00, 1.60e-08, 3.20e-08, 4.80e-08, 6.40e-08, 8.00e-08, 9.60e-08, 1.10e-07, 1.20e-07, 1.40e-07, 1.60e-07, 1.70e-07, 1.92e-07, 2.00e-07, 2.24e-07, 2.40e-07, 2.56e-07, 2.72e-07])]
```

Comment: What you have tried or researched so far?

Comment: Careful, you are redefining the internal class `list` here and since you use the class `array` you probably want to include the `numpy` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first array is the first element in the list lt.

```
lt = [array([ 1.25e-02, -5.79e-03,  7.32e-03, -1.40e-02, 1.73e-02,  3.35e-03,  1.28e-02,  2.59e-02, 4.57e-03,  2.56e-02,  2.44e-03,  1.12e-02]), array([0.00e+00, 1.60e-08, 3.20e-08, 4.80e-08, 6.40e-08, 8.00e-08, 9.60e-08, 1.10e-07, 1.20e-07, 1.40e-07, 1.60e-07, 1.70e-07, 1.92e-07, 2.00e-07, 2.24e-07, 2.40e-07, 2.56e-07, 2.72e-07])]
max_value = lt[0].max(axis=1)
max_index = lt[0].argmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it:

`np.argmax(mylist[0])`